# WebSVN Permissions Issue

Tags: linux, svn, apache, websvn

This is the error I get:

E180001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///svn/repositories/ncs_svn'
\nE180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
\nE180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///svn/repositories/ncs_svn'
\nE000013: Can't open file '/svn/repositories/ncs_svn/format': Permission denied

I can run this command from the command  line as root and it works.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As it is written in your question you don't have permission to `/svn/repositories/ncs_svn/format`.    Try to set permission for user.

Comment: The directory and all files are set to '666'.  Isn't that enough?  I don't know what user executes the command.

Comment: You can try to change it. Or check access to directory of upper level.